# Running a Query with a CursorLoader in android

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

I am trying to run a cursor with a cursorloader in order to perform a query against one of my database tables to retrieve a list of categories.

So I am adapting below example to mine:
[listview example using cursor loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Problems I have currently:

1. I get errors when setting progressBar.setLayoutParams (see later
   in this post) and I do not know exactly how to set it. In the example it is not specified what kind of object is LayoutParams, I guess it is ViewGroup but it only accepts 2 parameters and not 3 (so I do not use Gravity.CENTER in my example).
2. When I create a new instance of CursorLoader (new CursorLoader) in method    onCreateLoader, second parameter is an URI object. I do not know exactly what it is, I
   thought it was the database table name, in my case, DBContract.Category.TABLE_NAME but I get errors on compile saying it is not valid.
   (see later my code in this post)
3. When I create a new instance of the ViewGroup in "CategorySelectorActivity.java" class: ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
   I have no idea to adapt to mine, I have no idea on what I have to put instead android.R.id.content. What do I have to put here instead according to my below code?

Could someone help me, please?

Below I show my code.

I have an activity called "activity_categoryselector.xml" which its content is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip"

tools:context="com.myPackage.myApp.CategorySelectorActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Description"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/firstLine"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With above code I want to have each list view item consisting on an image (left) and two textviews (right). One textview over the another.

The java class for this activity is called "CategorySelectorActivity.java" and its content adapted from the example posted in the above link (at the beginning of this post) is:

```
    public class CategorySelectorActivity extends ListActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    // This is the Adapter being used to display the list's data
    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    // Category rows to retrieve from database
    static final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {DBContract.Category._ID,
            DBContract.Category.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE};

    // Criteria selection
    static final String SELECTION = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a progress bar to display while the list loads
        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        progressBar.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        getListView().setEmptyView(progressBar);

        // Must add the progress bar to the root of the layout
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        root.addView(progressBar);

        // For the cursor adapter, specify which columns go into which views
        String[] fromColumns = {DBContract.Category.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE};
        int[] toViews = {R.id.firstLine}; // The TextView in activity_categoryselector layout

        // Create an empty adapter we will use to display the loaded data.
        // We pass null for the cursor, then update it in onLoadFinished()
        // Custom row layout
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.activity_categoryselector, null,
                fromColumns, toViews, 0);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Prepare the loader.  Either re-connect with an existing one,
        // or start a new one.
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    // Called when a new Loader needs to be created
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        return new CursorLoader(this, DBContract.Category.TABLE_NAME,
                PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
    }

    // Called when a previously created loader has finished loading
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        // Swap the new cursor in.  (The framework will take care of closing the
        // old cursor once we return.)
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    // Called when a previously created loader is reset, making the data unavailable
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // This is called when the last Cursor provided to onLoadFinished()
        // above is about to be closed.  We need to make sure we are no
        // longer using it.
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Do something when a list item is clicked
        String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, item + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Finally my contract class which shows my database schema (I only show here the table used in this example) is something like this:

```
public final class DBContract {
// Empty constructor to prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class,
public DBContract() {}

/* Inner classes that defines the tables contents */

....

// Categories table
public static abstract class Category implements BaseColumns {
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "category";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME_NULLABLE = "null";
}

....
}
```

Comment: You can not use cursor loader without content provider!

Comment: How can I use a content provider to adapt this? I'm sorry... I have no idea about content providers.... could you help me by providing me a link to somewhere with a complete example, please? or indicate me on how can I do the content provider.

Comment: Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html), then after understanding it search on google some thing like `how to use cursor loader with content provider`, or `cursor loader example`, you will find a lot of code.

Comment: @mmlooloo ok, many thanks, I will have a look.